# Selenium First Java Script

Tags: java, selenium

I'm new to selenium and I tried to code my first java script using selenium.

[image]

It is giving errors as follows:

**- WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type

- ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type
- Watchpoint:FirstSelleniumScript [access and modification] - driver**

I have added selenium to the libaries- selenium-java-3.141.59

java version "1.8.0_251"

I can't understand how to fix it.

Comment: You have to `import` them.

Comment: And as a side note, please don't post pictures of code. Post the actual code instead.

Comment: `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;`

Comment: The import org.openqa cannot be resolved. I'm still getting this error.I can't import

Answer (score 0):

Import Necessary Files

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

Download The Compatible
[ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Now in function you have set the path for chromedriver in your method

```
String chromePath = "C:/Common_Resourses/";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath + "chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

You can also Read more About browser [capabilities](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities), it will help you with browser handling

Comment: The import org.openqa cannot be resolved. I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set property first and import chrome driver.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class TestChrome {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the exe file\\chromedriver.exe");
// Initialize browser
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Also refer this video https://youtu.be/c86GdHQaLsY

Comment: Please post code as text, not as pictures.

Comment: The import org.openqa cannot be resolved. I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Did u import selenium jars to eclipse. If not pls watch this https://youtu.be/7yYDOja8n_k